# R Subset dataframe by factor to new dataframes with factor names

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe 'df' that has a column with a factor that looks like:

| Species |
| --- |
| CANG |
| CANG |
| AMRO |
| AMRO |
| MOBL |
| MOBL |
| MOBL |

I would like to create a new data frame for each factor level with the name of the data frame being the factor level so that I end up with:

'CANG'

| Species |
| --- |
| CANG |
| CANG |

'AMRO'

| Species |
| --- |
| AMRO |
| AMRO |

'MOBL'

| Species |
| --- |
| MOBL |
| MOBL |
| MOBL |

Comment: Use `split(df1, df1$Species)`

Comment: Is there a way to have each dataframe saved into the global environment in R studio?

Comment: Yes, `list2env(split(df1, df1$Species), .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: This worked great. Thank you very much! Would you be able to go to a chat so I can ask a simple follow up about the split and ggplot?

Comment: @Jacob you almost certainly don't need to split your data before using ggplot. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Im trying to create a separate histogram for each level of a factor in a column.